# Parse json using jq utility & append fields together

Tags: jq

One of the many thousand json blocks in an array of json blocks looks as follows -

```json
{
  "id": 4409976,
  "name": "MKLIU",
  "version": "1.0",
  "package_type": "generic",
  "status": "default",
  "_links": {
    "web_path": "/part1/part2/ONEMTH/part4/-/part5/part6",
    "delete_api_path": "https://example.com/api/v1/part40/part90/part65/part73"
  },
  "created_at": "2019-01-02T10:52:34.857Z",
  "project_id": 667845,
  "project_path": "hereitis/downloads/ONEMTH/MKLIU",
  "tags": []
}
```

I am looking to parse the array of json blocks on Ubuntu command line using `jq` utility

**Expected output**

```
667845#MKLIU#ONEMTH
```

The code I've written so far is as below

```
curl <some url> | jq -r '.[] | [.project_id, .name, ._links.web_path] | join("#")'
```

I can't work out how to pull out just the part `ONEMTH` from `._links.web_path`

Could use `project_path` field too from the json block to parse out the value.

Please could I request some guidance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use the [split/1](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#split(str)) method on a delimiter(`/`) and extract the field required by specifying the index

```
[ .project_id, .name, (._links.web_path | split("/")[3]) ] | join("#")
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/XXsqpZuVAo) - working demo

Answer (score 2):

For just the one object you show, which corresponds to your code after `.[]`: you can use string interpolation and `split` / array indexing to extract the web path string:

```sh
jq -r '"\(.project_id)#\(.name)#\(._links.web_path | split("/")[3])"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get the desired output.

```
echo $(curl <some-url> | jq -r '.[] | [.project_id, .name] | join("#")' && curl <some-url> | jq -r '.[] |  ._links.web_path' | awk -F/ '{ print $4}') | tr ' ' '#'
```

PS: There may be a more optimal way to achieve this. Comments are welcome!

Comment: Great effor. Thank you Shankar. No this isn't working :(

Comment: @usert4jju7, i have editted the answer. I had mistakenly used cat instead of a curl. If you haven't noticed that then could you try it again? Else could you point out some error in output?

Answer (score 1):

One can accomplish this with:

```sh
$ jq '{ project_id, name, "path": ._links.web_path | split("/") | .[3] } | join ("#")' < example.txt
"667845#MKLIU#ONEMTH"
```

The `project_id` and `name` fields are "passed through" from the input. You didn't specify the exact rules for pulling out your target substring, `"ONEMTH"`, from the `_links.web_path` key. The above assumes it's always the fourth element resulting from splitting the string on `"/"`. Please update your question if that's not always the case.

The data is then collected into an object, rather than array, and the values joined by the `"#"` character.

Interestingly, using an array here doesn't seem to work:

```sh
$ jq '[.project_id, .name, ._links.web_path | split("/") | .[3]] | join ("#")' < example.txt
jq: error (at <stdin>:14): split input and separator must be strings
```

I'm not sure why. The `jq` documentation [explicitly states](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#TypesandValues) that array elements may be pipelines, so it seems like that should be fine. But in any case, the former works!

Comment: The comma operator `,` has a higher precedence than the pipe operator `|`. That's why in the array `[.project_id, .name, ._links.web_path | split("/") | …]` first the comma will produce (a stream of) three items and then `split` is applied separately to **each** of them. This fails in the case of `.project_id` which is a `number`, not a `string`. The correct way to change precedence is to use parentheses: `[.project_id, .name, (._links.web_path | split("/") | …)]`. That way, only `._links.web_path` will be further processed before the (streamed) items will become one array.

Comment: @pmf Thanks, that makes sense. I hadn't seen anything about operator precedence or grouping on the `jq` man pages, but I'm not a heavy user TBH. I appreciate the explanation.